# Two-variable p-adic L-functions of elliptic curves

Tags: nt.number-theory, iwasawa-theory, p-adic-analysis, l-functions

Suppose $K$ is an imaginary quadratic field (with class number 1, for simplicity), $p \ne 2$ a prime split in $K$, and $K_\infty$ the $\mathbb{Z}_p^2$-extension of $K$.

If $E / \mathbb{Q}$ is an elliptic curve with CM by $K$, then there is a construction (due to Katz) for a "two-variable $p$-adic $L$-function" attached to $E$, which is a $p$-adic measure on the Galois group $K_\infty / K$, interpolating $L$-values of the twists of the Groessencharacter of $K$ attached to $E$ by finite-order characters of p-power conductor. See e.g. de Shalit's book "Iwasawa theory of elliptic curves with complex multiplication" (Academic Press, 1987)

If $E / \mathbb{Q}$ is any elliptic curve with good ordinary reduction at $p$ (or more generally any ordinary modular form of weight $\ge 2$), but not necessarily with CM by $K$, there is also a construction of a two-variable $L$-function attached to $E$, written down by Perrin-Riou (J. London Math. Soc 38 (1988), 1-32) based on earlier work by Hida and others. This interpolates $L$-values of the twists of $E$ by certain 2-dimensional Artin representations of $\mathbb{Q}$, obtained by inducing up finite-order characters of $\operatorname{Gal}(K_\infty / K)$.

My question is this: if we apply Perrin-Riou's method to an $E$ which happens to have CM by $K$, then what is the relation between the $L$-functions coming from the two constructions?

(My impression is that Perrin-Riou's construction should give the product of Katz's $L$-function with its conjugate, corresponding to the decomposition of the Tate module of $E$ as a $\operatorname{Gal}(\overline{K} / K)$-representation into the direct sum of two conjugate characters. But I'm puzzled by the discrepancy of coefficient fields: Perrin-Riou's measure takes values in some finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, while Katz's lives in the completion of the unramified $\mathbb{Z}_p$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, which is far larger.)

Comment: My understanding is that if your E is CM and ordinary, then Katz's measure can be shown to live in in some finite extension of Qp as well, but this is based more on general expectations that on any direct knowledge I have of the construction of Katz.

Comment: +1. I would be also interested to know the answer! I remember being told that the Katz two-variable p-adic L-function specializes to the classical (one-variable) p-adic L-function of E, but I don't know about your more general question.

Comment: @Olivier: I'm sorry, that's not true. (The values of Katz's L-function at algebraic characters involve a period $\Omega_p$ which is transcendental over $\mathbb{Q}_p$.)

Comment: @David: maybe one just needs to divide the Katz L-function by $\Omega_p$ ? Indeed there is no "p-adic period" in the definition of the classical p-adic L-function.

Comment: Again, I really don't know but, generally speaking, p-adic periods arise as determinants of comparison isomorphisms. If your motive is ordinary to begin with, these comparison isomorphisms and the determinants in question live in your original ring of coefficients. At any rate, this is certainly what happens on the algebraic side, which is the only one I really know anything about. But perhaps I am talking non-sense here, and I really should strop writing before I know more about this $\Omega_{p}$. 

Comment: Work of Tsuji on Explicit Reciprocity Laws and Bloch-Kato
is relevant:

Tsuji, Takeshi(J-TOKYOGM)
Explicit reciprocity law and formal moduli for Lubin-Tate formal groups. (English summary) 
J. Reine Angew. Math. 569 (2004), 103–173. 



Comment: @Francois, Olivier: there is a character $\chi$ (the Galois character corresponding to the Groessencharacter of E) such that the value of Katz's L-function at $\chi^k$ is $\Omega_p^k$ times an element of $\overline{Q}$, so just "dividing out by $\Omega_p$" doesn't work -- moreover, there is no element of the Iwasawa algebra taking the value $\Omega_p^k$ at $\chi^k$ for all $k$.
@Jeremy: Thanks for the suggestion, I will look at Tsuji's paper.

Comment: This is just a comment, because I have not read the through Katz's construction in detail. My impression is that the problem could be a very hard one, because there would be an implicit need to compare the p-adic period(s) in Katz with the period used in Hida/Perrin-Riou (the Petersson inner product of the underlying eigenform). Also, note that the two-variable measure of Hida/Perrin-Riou can be seen to take integral values in the field of definition, as a consequence of the fact that Hida's bounded linear form sends integral-valued forms to integral-valued forms (which is easy to check).

Comment: @David: why is there no Iwasawa function interpolating powers of $\Omega_p$?

Comment: @Jupiter Jones: let $F$ be such a function. Then $F$ has to satisfy $F(x + y + xy) = F(x)F(y)$ (because this is true when $x$ and $y$ are powers of $1 + p$ and these are Zariski-dense). Hence its restriction to the set of points $S = \{\zeta - 1 : \zeta \in \mu_{p^\infty}\}$ would have to be a homomorphism $\mu_{p^\infty} \to \mathbb{C}_p^\times$, all of which are given by elements of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions on K in Perrin - Riou's paper (Heegner hypothesis) probably exclude the case that we can take K to be the field of complex multiplication.

Comment: The Heegner hypothesis, as I understand it, is that all primes $\ell \mid N$ are split in $K$. P-R doesn't assume this, but she does assume that all primes dividing $N$ are *unramified* in K. It is true that this does actually exclude the case I'm looking at here, but I'm pretty sure that this is more for simplification than because it's essential to the method.